# RHEL Postgresql 9.4 and PostGIS

Tags: postgresql, linux, postgresql-9.4, postgis, redhat

I'm a dba new to postgresql. I have Linux RedHat 7 **without** openshift.

I have to install some DB on 9.4 version with postgis.

My sysadmin has published the following repositories :

- RHEL 7 server
- RHEL 7 EPEL
- yum.postgresql.org for 9.2, 9.3 and 9.4

I managed to install :

- Postgres 9.2 from postgresql.org repo with postgis 2.1 for PG9.2
- Postgres 9.4 from RH repo

And the issue is when I want to have PostGis for PG9.4, I can't find it anywhere in the repos.

Which repo, which package should I have to get PostGis for PG9.4 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will probably want the [postgis2_94.x86_64](http://yum.postgresql.org/9.4/redhat/rhel-7-x86_64/repoview/postgis2_94.html) package from the `pgdg94` repository, because that is the official RPM package repository for the PostgreSQL project. It also includes a rich ecosystem of tools around PostgreSQL in addition to all of the currently supported PostgreSQL releases according to the [Versioning Policy](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/) of the PostgreSQL project.

Comment: Thanks, it was easy but helped à lot. My sysadmin had a filter on his sattelite which prevent the correct package to show up.